# How to measure independent variables in different combinations influence the dependent variable

Tags: multiple-regression

[image]

EDIT: How to measure ALL independent variables in ALL and DIFFERENT combinations influence the dependent variable (PLEASE see the above image for what I need to do)

I'm given a large dataset with 6 independent variables and 1 dependent variable.

My goal is to measure how all of the 6 independent variables (all of them in different combinations) influence the dependent variable (like what I put in the image above).

ANOVA / Multiple linear regression analysis / OLS regression doesn't work because it only has 1 independent variable VS. 1 dependent variable.

MNOVA / Turkey HSD post-hoc test doesn't work because it measures 2 independent variables VS. 1 dependent variable.

What can I do to complete this analysis? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Multiple regression, by definition, incorporates *more* than one independent variable.  See our posts with the [tag:multiple-regression] tag.